# Finding formula using tangentline information

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm new on SE, but I hope that you guys will help me with this question I have.
I'm currently not capable of using $\LaTeX$ or anything nice to set up my formulas, but I hope you will bear over with that - at least for now.

I have the following information:

A function $f$ solves the differential equation

$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x+5-y$

And the line with the equation $y=1$ (I notice the two $y$'s as well...) is a tangent line to $f$.

And my question is then:

How do I find the formula for $f$ using only this information?

What I have done so far (basically only using separation of variables):

$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x+5-y$

$\frac{dy}{y} = (2x+5)dx$

$\int(1/y)dy = \int(2x+5)dx$

$\ln(y) = x^2 + 5x + k$

$y=e^{x^2 + 5x + k}$

Also I would be pleased if you would check if what I have done is correct, as I have not actually learned separation of variables yet...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= 2x+5-y\\
y'+y&=2x+5
\end{align}
This is [first order linear ODE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#First_order_equation): $y'+f(x)y=g(x)$. You have $f(x)=1$, then the integrating factor is
\begin{align}
e^{\int f(x)\ dx}=e^{\int \ dx}=e^{x+C}=Ae^x
\end{align}
where $A=e^C$. Multiply both sides of $y'+y=2x+5$ by the integrating factor.
\begin{align}
Ae^xy'+Ae^xy&=(2x+5)Ae^x\\
e^xy'+e^xy&=(2x+5)e^x\\
\frac{d}{dx}(e^xy)&=(2x+5)e^x\\
d(e^xy)&=(2x+5)e^x\,dx\\
\int d(e^xy)&=\int(2x+5)e^x\,dx\\
\end{align}
Use integration by parts to solve the RHS integral. Let $u=2x+5$, $du=2\,dx$, $dv=e^x\,dx$, and $v=e^x$.
\begin{align}
\int d(e^xy)&=\int(2x+5)e^x\,dx\\
e^xy&=(2x+5)e^x-\int e^x\cdot2\,dx\\
e^xy&=(2x+5)e^x-2e^x+C\\
y&=2x+5-2+Ce^{-x}\\
&=2x+3+Ce^{-x}\\
\end{align}

Comment: I forgot this one. Since $y=1$ (its slope is $0$) is a tangent line to $f(x)$, then $f'(x)=0$.
\begin{align}
y&=2x+3+Ce^{-x}\\
y'&=2-Ce^{-x}\\
0&=2-Ce^{-x}\\
Ce^{-x}&=2
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
y&=2x+3+Ce^{-x}\\
1&=2x+3+2\\
x&=-2
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
Ce^{-x}&=2\\
Ce^{-(-2)}&=2\\
C&=2e^{-2}
\end{align}
Hence
\begin{align}
y(x)=2x+3+2e^{-(x+2)}
\end{align}

Comment: Well, I thought I was done with this question, but I guess not after all... At the beginning of your "integration by parts"-section you have $\int d(e^xy) = \int(2x+5)e^x dx$.

How exactly do you work with an integral (LHS) without a differential. I would appreciate either an explanation or a link, thank you.

Comment: @user147163 I hope this link helps you: [Integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts).

Comment: I'm sorry to keep digging into this, as I'm not sure how big of a deal it really is. But it just seems like I'm missing something. I'll try again. I do (think I) understand the integration by parts...

What I don't understand is
how does $\int d(e^xy) = e^xy$ give any meaning? (that is to me how it appears...)

To me it should be $\int d(e^xy) \mathbf{dx} = e^xy$

Well, maybe not even that... I'm just unsure of the missing differential in the integral.

Thanks again

Comment: @user147163: Maybe these examples will help you.
$$
\int\, dx=x
$$
and
$$
\int\, dy=y
$$
Similarly
$$
\int\, d(\sin x)=\sin x
$$
also
$$
\int\, d(e^x)=e^x
$$
The last parts are only integration by substitution by letting $u=\sin x$ and $u=e^x$. Of course we should add a constant but I neglect it so you can easily understand it.

Comment: I thank you again. Is this called something specific? (so that I can do a seach for it) Because I have never seen these before and would like to know how to evaluate them more precisely.

Comment: Integration by substitution: [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) and [2](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/SubstitutionRuleIndefinite.aspx)

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't making myself clear. I am familiar with integration by substitution.
I was looking for something rather like a proof (or something like that - maybe a definition?) that $\int dx$ is actually equivalent to $x$. Thanks

Comment: $$\huge\int\, dx=\int \color{red}1\, dx=x$$

Comment: Well, that I must say was a revalation to me! I appreciate your time, thank you!